# Should I flag when the poster of a question trolls in comments?

Tags: discussion

*Disclaimer: I checked for dups of this. Saw similar-ish answers but didn't cover this angle (at least that I could see in a quick search).*

---

I bumped into a question in triage by a poster who's been here three years, and asked three questions, all heavily downvoted.

He posted a question containing a short passage of badly formatted code. As people were trying to respond in comments, he was trolling them in comments.:  **"Please help meeeeeeeeeeeee!"** and some other snarky comment a little more blatant, but I don't remember the text exactly.

I probably should have just voted to close and downvoted it, but I decided to flag it as rude or abusive because of his obvious deliberate trolling in comments.  But the flag was declined citing no evidence was found to support the flag. So, I went back and looked at the post, but the trolling comments were gone (assume deleted by the poster?) with no obvious trail.

So, is it ever appropriate to flag for comments of any kind? 
I don't want to harm my own reputation with moderators if someone can come along, delete the comments and no one is any the wiser.

Comment: I have my doubts that this is intentionally trolling; it could *easily* be the case that the OP really needs the help and wants to project their urgencies unto us, which never bodes well.

Comment: not sure of the other comments but the one you quoted seems more begging than trolling....though still probably flag worthy of non-constructive

Comment: I don't know if moderators have access to the deleted comments, but taken alone I wouldn't have considered the comment I mentioned above as trolling. It became obvious that it was more trollish in context of his other response, IIRC, which I don't remember verbatim, or hardly at all with each passing minute.  But also suspect is the fact that those comments are now deleted, as though the poster knew they were controversial.... But regardless of this specific case, let's say someone *was* deliberately and blatantly trolling, then deleted comments...? Would it be better to flag "rude" or not?

Comment: though assuming i found the right question and looking at that user's other posts (the 2 answers they posted) it seems they might be trolling. their question is incomplete code, one of their answers is a request for help with a dump of xml and the other is a sentence in another language.

Comment: @Memor-X Yup. That's the one.

Comment: Diamond mods can see deleted comments. You don't need to leave a bannered note to them in the comments. Just explain the situation thoroughly in your custom flag.

Comment: I flagged as "Rude or Abusive", so I guess a custom flag is the way to go. Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, OK. I took your comment there to mean that you'd already raised custom flag asking for deletion.

Comment: @MikeM. Removed banner. Get the hang of this more as I go. Thanks. BTW: If I reply to you immediately after your comment, do I have to specify you, or do you get the notification anyway?

Comment: If there's more than one other user in a comment section, you need to use @username, unless they're the owner of the post.

Comment: One thing I'm not entirely clear on: you flagged the post, right? You did not flag the comments? That is another course of action that could have gotten the comments removed by the way: people flagging them. It did not have to be the author of the comments cleaning up.

Comment: Oh, duh! I forgot comments can be individually flagged. I've seen the icon before but never needed to use it so tuned it out and haven't really noticed. So next time there's that too. Thanks.